# check if two array have any value same

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any way I could check if two arrays contain the same value?

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string '209' (length=3)

array (size=4)
  0 => string '209' (length=3)
  1 => string '208' (length=3)
  2 => string '1' (length=1)
  3 => string '2' (length=1)
```

I want to see if I can get 209 they match in both array

Answer (score 1):

You can use two functions in combination. First would be array_intersect which will pick the common values between arrays.

`$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);`

This can contain duplicates as well. So after this you can filter values using

`$result = array_unique($result)`

These will be the common values between both arrays.

Comment: why array_unique???? which duplicate value? array_intersect will retrun `Array
(
    [0] => 209
)`

Comment: array_intersect(array(1,2,2),array(1,2,3)); //=> array(1,2,2)

Comment: but this is not a rrequirement

Comment: Now there are 2 times number 2. ;)

Comment: For big arrays it is useful to remove duplicates. Yes not a requirement .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function for that

```
$searchVal = '209';
if (in_array($searchVal, $array1) && in_array($searchVal, $array2)) {
   echo "$searchVal is in both arrays!";
}
```

You can even make it into a function if you need to reuse this code alot:

```
function in_arrays($needle, $array1, $array2) {
    if (in_array($needle, $array1) && in_array($needle, $array2)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// in use:
$searchVal = '209';
if(in_arrays($searchVal, $firstArray, $secondArray) {
    echo "$searchVal is found in both arrays";
}
```

Comment: This works but I don't want to type manually 209
209 is in array1
209 is in array2 aswell

Comment: @jibingeorge Well you can just replace the 209 with a variable, I've edited my answer.